# convert int to float in MIPS assembly

Tags: assembly, mips

My method is to spill the int register and load into the float register and then convert

```
li $t0, 2       
sw $t0, -88($fp)    
l.s $f4, -88($fp)
cvt.d.s $f6, $f4
```

I'm trying to translate an expression like

```
float a = 3.0;
float b = a / 2;
```

But the above method doesn't give me a proper answer (print out `inf`).

So where have I done wrong? Any suggestions?

P.S.  `2` doesn't know the lhs operand is a float type so I can not load `2.0` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incorrect suffix; `.d` will operate on a double word (64 bit). Here's what you want:

```
li   $t0, 2
sw   $t0, -88($fp)
lwc1 $f4, -88($fp)
cvt.s.w $f6, $f4
```